# Why does my character continue to move briefly after I remove my finger from the movement key?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Why do I either lag or keep walking or jumping after my finger's off the key in Minecraft? When I press W to walk or SPACE to jump most of the time it won't walk for a second, then keep walking.

Comment: Are you on a server or single player? Is your laptop older or has lower end specs? Is your laptop running hot and/or hard?

Comment: How long? In Creative, the gradual slowdown is intended (although I find it annoying and I think it doesn't exist in MCBE, there's also some mod to remove it in MCJava). If you mean that you keep walking at regular speed for multiple seconds after you have intentionally used that button for a while (probably minutes), then I think there is some issue like that, but I don't know the exact report. I have experienced it myself, but not often, I don't know the exact conditions and whether it's because of Minecraft, the operating system or my wireless keyboard. Are you using a wireless keyboard?